# Performing sine function and arithmetical operations on a data frame with special columns(columns with lists)

Tags: r, dataframe, trigonometry

I have a data frame **df1** with list columns

```
df1 <- data.frame(w= 1:3, x=3:5, y=6:8, z = I(list(1:2, 1:3, 1:4)))

> df1
  w x y          z
1 1 3 6       1, 2
2 2 4 7    1, 2, 3
3 3 5 8 1, 2, 3, 4
```

I have transformed **df1** into a second data frame **df2** by multiplying every other column of **df1** with the column z:

```
df2<- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(df[1:3], function(x) Map("*", df$z, x))))

> df2
            w             x             y
1        1, 2          3, 6         6, 12
2     2, 4, 6      4, 8, 12     7, 14, 21
3 3, 6, 9, 12 5, 10, 15, 20 8, 16, 24, 32
```

I want to create a third data frame , **df3**  by multiplying **df2** by pi, then taking the sine function of the result and multiplying the sine output by 4 while preserving the data frame structure. I wish to be able to perform the operation with the most time-effective method possible since I am working with a much larger data frame:

```
df3 <- as.data.frame (4*sin(df2*pi))
```

Considering that the Map function accepts not more than two parameters, I have attempted a solution like this which unfortunately is taking a an infinitely long time:

```
df3 <- lapply(df2, function(x) Map("*",vol, Map("sin", Map("*",pi, x))))
```

I will be very grateful for any hint on how to perform the following operation in the most time-effective way.

```
df3 <- as.data.frame (4*sin(df2*pi))
```

My expected out put is to have a data frame **df3** where each element
is the same as 4*sin(df2[i,k]).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use `Map(function(a,b,c,d,...,z){}, a,b,c,d,...,z)` for more than two parameters?

Comment: lapply(z, function(x) Map(function(x){4*(sin(x*pi))}, x)) gives the required output. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `Map` here. `Map` is a wrapper around `mapply` that autodefines `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`. For the creation of `df3`, you do not have multiple arguments, therefore `lapply` is sufficient:

```
df3 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(df2, function(x){
  lapply(x, function(y){
    4*sin(y*pi)
  })
})))

> df3
                                                         w                                                        x
1                              4.898425e-16, -9.796851e-16                              1.469528e-15, -2.939055e-15
2              -9.796851e-16, -1.959370e-15, -2.939055e-15                 -1.95937e-15, -3.91874e-15, -5.87811e-15
3 1.469528e-15, -2.939055e-15, 4.408583e-15, -5.878110e-15 2.449213e-15, -4.898425e-15, 2.155849e-14, -9.796851e-15
                                                           y
1                               -2.939055e-15, -5.878110e-15
2                 3.428898e-15, -6.857796e-15, -3.924161e-15
3 -3.918740e-15, -7.837481e-15, -1.175622e-14, -1.567496e-14
```

Comment: Please is it possible to provide a hint on how to do it by interfacing with C++? I think it will be dramatically faster.

Answer (score 1):

You may flatten `df2` to a vector and perform `4*sin(pi*x)` in one call.
`relist` helps to transform back to the initial structure:

```
df3 <- 4 * sin(unlist(df2) * pi)
df3 <- as.data.frame(
  do.call(cbind, relist(df3, as.list(df2))))
```